# How to prevent linux xrdp from spanning multiple monitors

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, centos

I installed xrdp on centos 7 server. Am trying to connect to it using rdp from a windows 2012 box with "Use all monitors .." option selected.

Once I get into  the centos box, I see that the display is spanning both monitors that are connected. As a result, if i maximize chrome in the centos instance, it spans both monitors instead of just filling one monitor.

Tried the same by replacing the windows 2012 box with a windows 2008 r2 box.

Any ideas??